# Expanding a "true" eigenfunction using adiabatic eigenfunctions as a basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This may be (and probably is) a dumb question, but I'm a little confused so any insight would be most welcome.

In the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, we separate the problem into an electronic Schrodinger equation $\psi(r,R)$ and a nuclear equation $\phi(R)$. We first solve the electronic Schrodinger to find $\psi(r,R)$ with the positions of the nuclei treated as a fixed parameter and then we solve the nuclear Schrodinger to find $\phi(R)$. We now have (approximate) eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian for our system.

My textbook points out that the "true" eigenfunction can be expanded using the "adiabatic eigenfunctions" as a basis. I presume the adiabatic eigenfunctions are those approximate eigenfunctions we have found using the procedure described above? I am also a little unclear on how to expand this. Let's say I expand as the sum of a coefficient times the product of each of the nuclear and electronic eigenfunctions I found above; how is this coefficient to be found? Normally to find the coefficient $i$ for expansion in a basis I would take the inner product of the basis vector $i$ with the wavefunction itself. Given that we do not know and cannot find the "true eigenfunction" of this system, however, how can I calculate the coefficient for each component of this expansion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\hat{H}_{Total}=\hat{H}_{Nuclear}+\hat{H}_{Electronic},$$
where $$\hat{H}_{Nuclear}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{R}_{n}}^{2}}{m_{n}^{}}$$ and 
$$\hat{H}_{Electronic}=- \frac{\hbar^2}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{M}\frac{\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{r}_{m}}^{2}}{m_{e}^{}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j =1}^{M}\frac{e^2}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_{j}|}- \sum_{i =1}^{M}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{Z_{j}e^2}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{R}_{j}|}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i\neq j =1}^{N}\frac{Z_{i}Z_{j}e^2}{|\vec{R}_{i}-\vec{R}_{j}|}$$
You want to solve the eigenvalue equation 
$$\hat{H}_{Total}\Psi(\{r\},\{R\})=E\Psi(\{r\},\{R,\}).$$
First solve for complete set of electronic adiabatic states parametrically dependent on nuclear geometry as :
$$H_{Electronic}(r,R)\psi_{n}^{}(\{r\};\{R\})=e_{n}^{}(\{R\}) \psi_{n}^{}(\{r\};\{R\}).$$
Now the total molecular wave function can be expanded in terms of complete set of electronic wave functions as : 
$$\Psi(\{r\},\{R\})=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\phi_{n}^{}(\{R\})\psi_{k}^{}(\{r\};\{R\}),$$ 
with 
$$\phi_{k}^{}(\{R\})=\int d^{3}_{}\vec{r}_{1}^{}...\int d^{3}_{}\vec{r}_{M}^{} \psi_{k}^{*}(\{r\};\{R\}) \Psi(\{r\},\{R\}).$$
Now plugging the above defined Born-Oppenheimer expansion into the full molecular time independent Schrödinger's equation we can get the equation satisfied by nuclear wave functions $ \phi(\{R\})$. Lumping nuclear wave functions $\{\phi_{k}(\{R\})\}$ into a column vector $\phi(\{R\})$ of the form :
$$\phi(\{R\})=\begin{bmatrix}.\\.\\\phi_{k}(\{R\})\\.\\.\end{bmatrix},$$ 
satisfies a multicomponent time independent Schrodinger equation of the form :
$$\Bigg[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{m_{n}^{}}\Bigg(I_{K \times K}^{}\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{R}_{n}}^{}+{\vec{\tau}_{\vec{R}_{n}}}_{K \times K}\Bigg)^2_{}+V_{K \times K}(\{R\})\Bigg]\phi_{}^{}(\{R\})=E\phi(\{R\}),$$
where the matrix elements of the above defined '$K \times K$' matrices are respectively $$I_{mn}^{}=\delta_{mn}^{},$$ $${\vec{\tau}_{\vec{R}_{n}}}_{mn}^{}=\langle \psi_{m}^{}(\{r\};\{R\})|\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{R}_{n}}|\psi_{n}^{}(\{r\};\{R\})\rangle$$ and $$V_{mn}^{}(\{R\})=e_{m}^{}(\{R\})\delta_{mn}^{}.$$
For time dependent Schrodinger equation case, 
the same analysis can be carried out to get more aesthetic looking equation :
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi(\{R\},t)=\Bigg[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{m_{n}^{}}\Bigg(I_{K \times K}^{}\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{R}_{n}}^{}+{\vec{\tau}_{\vec{R}_{n}}}_{K \times K}\Bigg)^2_{}+V_{K \times K}(\{R\})\Bigg]\phi_{}^{}(\{R\},t).$$

Comment: Your `\grad`s display as errors on my device. Presumably you meant `\nabla`.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Now I fixed the typeset error. I am on mobile, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but mathematicians leave nabla without the vector arrow on top of it.

Comment: @DanielC Just wanted to write $\vec{\nabla}•\vec{\nabla}$.